# How can I make my site load example.html when somebody visits example.com/example

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, path, http-status-code-404

I have a file in my `public_html` folder called `example.html`.

When somebody visits `example.com/example.html`, they get a 404 response.

How can I make Apache serve `example.html` instead?

I have a bunch of files like that, so I'd prefer to create some kind of general rule instead of redirecting them all individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Turning RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine on

#Making sure a directory or file does not exist under that name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule {WHAT THE USER SEES} {WHAT IS CALLED}
RewriteRule ^example$ example.html
```

With this, loading `example.com/example` would show whatever `example.html` loads.

If you have a bunch of HTML files that you want to load in that format, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

You can put whatever regex you want in the first argument.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The comments were very helpful too.